# Error al ejecutar programa java error 740

Tags: java, sql-server

Tengo una aplicación de escritorio en java que debe descomprimir un archivo rar lo ejecuto con comando como si fuera consola por medio del método `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(l);` en modo debug funciona perfectamente pero cuando lo corro no extrae todos lo fichero y lo mismo me sucede con una clase de conexión a sql server en debug conecta y hace el insert pero lo corro y ni siquiera ingresa a la clase. Esto Ocurre en cualquier maquina que lo ejecute.

Comment: Parece que estás ejecutando código diferente al que tienes en tu IDE. Te recomiendo primero borrar todos los resultados de los compilados, luego recompilar todo y volver a ejecutar.

Comment: NO no funciono la verdad.

Comment: En ese caso se tienen que revisar más detalles del ambiente de ejecución. ¿Has comprobado que se ejecuta con la memoria necesaria? ¿Se tienen los permisos necesarios al momento de ejecutar tu aplicación? ¿Tienes un ambiente distinto a tu equipo de trabajo para ejecutar estas pruebas? ¿Hay algún stacktrace para revisar estos problemas? ¿Has utilizado un profiler en tiempo de ejecución para ver el rendimiento en tiempo real de la aplicación?

Comment: ya lo solucione es un problema de del metodo Runtime

Comment: @Jeferson, si ya lo solucionaste, puedes a) publicar tu solución como respuesta a esta pregunta o b) eliminar la pregunta. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

la solución era un problema con windows en los tiempos de ejecución el error 740 esto se debe a que estaba ejecutando la consola de cmd y la sentencia necesita permisos de administrado, la verdad la solución fue crea un archivo .bat que se ejecutara.